# number of loopback addresses

Tags: 16.04, networking, system, interface, localhost

I am following a networking course from udacity.

In one of the tutorials, the professor says that loopback address is almost always 127.0.0.1

So, it means it can be other than 127.0.0.1.

Can it be changed ? If yes, how ?

And also, at one moment, a machine can have only 1 loopback address, is it right ?

Comment: What does that have to with Ubuntu?

Comment: I just asked as I use ubuntu machine, and people answer here. I can flag it to migrate it if its inappropriate here.